# Unable to boot after adding 8GB of ram onto Macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro

Here are the specifications of the macbook pro

> ```
> Processor 2.66 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
> Memory 4 GB 1067 Mhz DDR3
> Lion 10.7.3
> 15-inch, Mid 2009
> Model Identifier: MacBookPro5,3
> ```

I am trying to add in 2x 4gb Ram of 1333mhz ddr3 into the macbook pro.  However i am only able to boot up with 1x2gb ddr 1067mhz and a 1x4gb 1333mhz. If i were to put in 2x4gb ram into the macbookpro, there will be a boot issue. weird sound will be heard.

Comment: Make sure your ram is seated correctly. Sounds coming out of the computer when upgrading ram isn't normal. It will either boot or not boot at all.

Comment: does it means that even if there is incompatibility issues such as higher mhz in the ram, the macbook will still not produce a sound?

Comment: Is it a beeping sound or a physical hardware sound? If it's beeping then the ram is not compatible.